# How to display two tabs inside the page/panel in Sencha Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

How to Display two tabs inside the page/panel in Sencha mobile application, and one should be active default?

Comment: Please read in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask. What did you try on your own and where in the process is your problem? This is not a Software development Service for free.

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide some more detail so we understand exactly what you are looking for.

To start here is the example from **ExtJS** 6.2.0 modern for `tabpanel`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'top',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [{
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        html: 'Home Screen'
    }, {
        title: 'Contact',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    }]
});
```

The home panel will display first as the default. Note when no xtype is defined it will default those to panels.